# get shared links on facebook newsfeed

Tags: php, facebook, graph, facebook-fql

I want to retrieve all the links shared on my wall using graph/fql, is there a way to get these

I am using fql query using friend list but that is not working, taking too long to respond.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?access_token=".$access_token_here));

foreach($json['data'] as $item){
   if ($item->link){
       $links[] = $item->link;
   }
}

print_r($links);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://youtu.be/r0a-o16i_Gw
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a good place to look for these. You want [/me/links](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flinks) to access the [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/) object. You'll need an [`access_token` from an authorized user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) who has granted the [`read_stream` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: Be carefule using /me/links. This will only show links that YOU have posted, and not links that others have shared on your wall. As I mentioned below, it will also exclude any posts which simply have the url in the status update, and not directly attached to the post.

Comment: Just an update: "links field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"